# Create centroid from field POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, centroid

I would like to create a centroid from a field that contains all the points that define a polygon. When apply the query for the coordinates is working but when trying to do the same for the field I get Invalid WKT: Invalid number: polygon (line 1)

My field "coord" contains data like:
46.781231 23.489355,46.785255 23.484876,46.786118 23.485407,46.787913 23.486857, 46.781231 23.489355

This one works :

```
SELECT  ST_centroid(ST_GeometryFromText('polygon((46.781231 23.489355,46.785255 23.484876,46.786118 23.485407,46.787913 23.486857, 46.781231 23.489355))'));
```

This one doesn't:

```
SELECT  ST_centroid(ST_GeometryFromText('polygon((coord))'))
from polygon_data;
```

Comment: Coord is not a WKT it is a column name, that will not work, just call the function on the column instead.

Comment: ST_centroid(ST_GeometryFromText('polygon(('||coord||'))')) works just perfect. Thanks for the hint. Have a nice day!